# Prove that A,B,C are mutually independent given that A and B, A and C, B and C are all pairwise independent. Stuck on circular logic, please help?

Tags: probability, independence

[To prove the mutual independence of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444652/to-prove-the-mutual-independence-of-events)

Here in this question,
"If A,B and C are random events in a sample space and if A,B and C are pairwise independent and A is independent of (B∪C), then is it true that A,B and C are mutually independent."

However, in this question,

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173192/if-a-and-b-are-independent-events-and-a-and-c-are-independent-events-h

for A to be independent of (B U C), A, B, and C must be mutually independent already? Is this circular reasoning? I am not sure how one statement can follow from the other.

My goal is to prove why A and (B U C) are independent of each other in Question #1, in order to prove that A, B, and C are mutually independent....but Question #2 says that in order for A and (B U C) to be independent of each other, A, B, and C must be mutually independent! so I am not sure where the flow of logic is coming from and where to begin for a proof of mutual independence between A, B, and C, given that A,B, B,C, and A,C are all pairwise independent.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the second link.  That link does not seem to say what you claim. Anyway the statement "for A to be independent of (B U C), A, B, C must be mutually independent" is false. Take $C$ as the entire sample space and let $A$ and $B$ be any dependent events.

Comment: Also, I cannot tell what your question is.  Your title seems different from anything in the body of the question, and the statement you want to prove in the title is false.

Comment: @Michael If the title is false, does that mean that pairwise independence already implies mutual independence among the three events? I am trying to show that P(ABC)=P(A)P(B)P(C) given that P(AB)=P(A)P(B), P(AC)=P(A)P(B), P(BC)=P(B)P(C)

Comment: @Michael I used the first link in order to prove P(ABC)=P(A)P(B)P(C), but then I got confused on their strategy for the proof by using the fact that A is independent of (B∪C), because I was not sure how they were able to come up with that. The second question confuses me because I am not sure why in order to prove A is independent of (BUC),the first answer says A B C must be independent, too. This is the circular reasoning I mentioned.

Comment: Your first comment does not make sense.  Your title is claiming that pairwise independence implies mutual independence, which is false. **Pairwise independence does not imply mutual independence.** Neither of the two links you provide are relevant, since you seem to be on the wrong track (trying to prove a false statement).

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense now